# How can I change php.ini by PHP?

Tags: php

I want to do the equivalent to the following line in file *php.ini*, but from PHP.

```
short_open_tag = On
```

Is it possible?

I tried this:

```
<?php
    if (!ini_get('short_open_tag')) {
        ini_set('short_open_tag', 'On');
    }
    $a = 1;
?>

<?=$a;?>
```

which outputs `<?=$a;?>`, so it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) is what you want.

An example:

```
if (!ini_get('short_open_tag')) {
    ini_set('short_open_tag', 'on');
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work for the author's example as the file has already been parsed by the time `ini_set()` is called. Besides, imo, short_open_tags should always be avoided because of the portability nightmares.

Comment: @Mike: You are right, I overlooked the question. It sounds like .htaccess will be a better alternative.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PHP 5.3, `short_open_tag` is no longer an option.

*[Description of core php.ini directives](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)*

Short tags have been deprecated as of PHP 5.3 and may be removed in PHP 6.0.

Comment: Agreed. You can not set short_open_tags at runtime. Souce: http://wiki.php.net/rfc/shortags. I'm not 100% certain that short_open_tags are being deprecated in PHP6 (It's been rumored but I've never seen confirmation) Sources http://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg41868.html and http://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg41845.html (but these are 8+ months old)

Comment: Mike you are correct, for a while they had said that 5.3 would deprecate short tags, but it is no longer posted that they will, I guess we will see.

Comment: What happened? Can you update? But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use [ini_set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php), be careful (quoted from the PHP documentation):

> Not all the available options can be changed using ini_set(). There is a list of all available options in the appendix.

If you are changing options, like *magic_quotes* and *short_open_tags*, that's OK. But if you are going to change *safe_mode*, *enable_dl*, etc., the function will fail silently.

Many of the options specified above as examples are obsolete/removed security options in former versions of PHP. Consult the documentation if the behavior of ini_set is unexpected (e.g., does not work)

Comment: Can you be more specific than *"face certain problems"*? Can you elaborate? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2025396/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Well this was written 11 years ago when the standards weren’t as clear as today :-) Thanks for pointing it out, fixed. Interestingly, all of the options I gave as examples are obsolete today.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change it during a session and forget about it later, use [ini_get()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php) and [ini_set()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php). If you want to actually modify *php.ini* programmatically, you can parse the ini file using [parse_ini_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php), change your options and rewrite back to disk. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) for more.

Or you can write your own string replacement routine using the normal opening of a file, [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please edit the *php.ini* file (just remove the `;` and restart your Apache server):

Replace

```
;short_open_tag = On
```

with

```
short_open_tag = On
```

Now it will work.